# Android Internet Radio Player

Tags: android-widget, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer, soundmanager2, android-mediarecorder

I am new in android. I have an internal project and selected an android Internet Radio player. here I don't know how to do...? But what i want to do is a simple player that will be just like an audio player when I press play button it will stream from internet or station that is selected from the list. I know what i will need for this.

1. Internet access to the application.
2. The list of station, now this is pretty much difficult for me to get list of stations available on different sites. I came to know from google that ShoutCast.com is one of best but I don't now how to get their station list.

Please anyone can help me for this app. I need emergency help or suggestion. It will be great help for me. Please.